# Preserve the state of a directive within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div change-color>Some content</div>
</div>
```

Where the directive "changeColor" can change the background color of the div by clicking it.

If I now change the content of my list, say by a HTTP-request which overwrites the whole list:

```
$scope.list = newList;
```

My "changeColor" directive "reloads", since the divs will be repopulated, is it possbile, by some angular-way to preserve the state of the div (by which the directive has changed it) or do I need to do it manually?

P.S.

This would be really useful since in my situation I have a huge list of items where the user wants to interact with each item in a way like above, but the list is overwritten each 30 seconds and that clears all the "changes" to it's pristine state.

Comment: this is data binding by angular, you will have to do it manually. you could also look at "bind-once". good luck.

Comment: have you tried the `track by` syntax?